# android retrofit 2 upload image to server

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, bearer-token

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWZot.png)

I'm new the Android developer, I'm working on an application, I have activity is users can upload their items to the server (the text and image), but the problem is upload text is easy , I used Volley to upload the text to server, but I struggle long time to upload the multiple the images to server. I saw the Retrofit 2 really good for multiple file upload but I have A lot problems.
I tried a lot but to no avail and I tried to share one of the codes with you so you can help me.

I also use bearer tokens but I don't know it is correct or not.

```
  File file1 = new File(patch_img1);
                File file2 = new File(patch_img2);
                File file3 = new File(patch_img3);

                RequestBody image1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),
                        file1);
                RequestBody image2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),
                        file2);
                RequestBody image3 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"),
                        file3);
                RequestBody invoice = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), invoices);
                UserSharedPref sharedPref = new UserSharedPref(CompletedServiceActivity.this);

                 WebServicesAPI request = APIClient.getApiClient("https://text.com/api/").create(WebServicesAPI.class);
                Call<ResponseBody> call = request.upload(sharedPref.getUserToken(),image1,image2,image3,invoice);


                call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
```

my interface.class

```
@POST("invoices")
Call<ResponseBody> upload(
        @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
        @Part("image1")  RequestBody image1,
        @Part("image2")  RequestBody image2,
        @Part("image3")  RequestBody image3,
         @Part("invoice") RequestBody invoice

);
```

APIClient.class

```
public class APIClient {

    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getApiClient(String url) {


        if (retrofit == null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's work with me :

```
String path3 = image3.getPath();
File file3 = new File(path3);
// Parsing any Media type file
RequestBody requestBody3 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file3);
MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload3 = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("filename", file3.getName(), requestBody3);
RequestBody filename3 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), image3.getName());
```

Calling method:

```
UploadImage3(fileToUpload3,filename3);
```

Interface:

```
@POST("uploadimage3.php")
@Multipart()
Observable<ApiResponse>UploadImage3(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("filename") RequestBody name);
```